# A counterexample to verify that composition is not commutative?

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, first-order-logic, substitution

Let $\theta=\{x_1\leftarrow t_1,\dots,x_n\leftarrow t_n\},\sigma =\{y_1\leftarrow s_1,\dots,y_m\leftarrow s_m\}$ and $\lambda=\{z_1\leftarrow r_1,\dots,z_k\leftarrow r_k\}$ be substitutions.

Prove that composition of substitutions it is not commutative.

So we want to see that in general $\theta\circ\sigma\ne\sigma\circ\theta.$

What could be the counterexample so that we can have $\theta\circ\sigma\ne\sigma\circ\theta$ ?

How can I construct the counterexample?

Help me please?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen really? Is that easy? can you believe that I don't know how

Comment: What does "substitution" mean in this question? Regardless, I suggest coming up with three substitutions, and see whether or not they all commute with each other. If they don't, you've found your counterexample. If they do, please edit this question to tell us which substitutions you tried.

Comment: Yes. (Well the inevitability of a randomly chosen pair of substitutions not being commutative is not strictly correct, but anyway.) Try just starting with an expression that is a single variable $x$ and try a pair of substitutions.

Comment: @TannerSwett It's the usual definition given in FOL course, intuitively you just replace an atom by another atom

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I don't understand how will I start with a single variable $x$. The attempt that I did is $\theta=\{x_1\leftarrow t_1\}$ and $\lambda=\{z_1\leftarrow t_1\}$ but I end up with $t_1=t_1$. Tell me what should I do to solve this ? Do I add more terms?

Comment: @Michelle What if $t_1$ contains a the variable $z_1$? (Perhaps, the problem you are having is definitions.) I'm suggesting you look at the action of the substitution when there's only one variable at play in the original formula, so perhaps the formula is $x=0$ for some constant symbol $0$... or it's $x=x.$ (Actually I was considering the action of the substitution on a term and suggesting you take the term $x$, but I suppose you are considering substitutions as acting on formulae... there's really not a substantial difference here.)

Comment: @Michelle I'll stop beating around the bush since maybe just seeing the example will help you understand the definitions: A counterexample is $x(x\rightarrow y)(y\rightarrow z)$ where $x,y,z$ are variables. We have $x(x\rightarrow y)(y\rightarrow z)= z$ and $x(y\rightarrow z)(x\rightarrow y) = y.$

Comment: @Michelle (Reverse the arrows in the above to conform to your notation.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I see, it's clear that $x(x\rightarrow y)(y\rightarrow z)= z$ but for the second expression I get $yz=y$ (I inverted the arrows)

Comment: @Michelle How do you get that? (It's not even clear to me what "that" is.) $x(y\leftarrow z) = x$ so $x(y\leftarrow z)(x\leftarrow y) = x(x\leftarrow y) = y.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I confused the composition, but now I'm more confused because of this $x(y\leftarrow z) = x$. That means you change $y$ by $z$ so you now have $z$. And then you apply $x$ to $z?$ so you have $x$ now?

Comment: @Michelle $x(y\leftarrow z)$ means we substitute $y$ for $z$ in the term $x.$ The  term $x$ does not have any $y$'s in it so it is unchanged by such a substitution. Then $x(x\leftarrow y)$ means we substitute $y$ for $x$ in the term $x,$ yielding $y.$ I don't know why you're 'applying' terms to terms (that isn't a thing syntactically speaking unless this is $\lambda$ calculus or something like that). You apply substitutions to terms, not terms to terms.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen ok I think I get it :) .Just I think you meant $x$ for $y$ instead of $y$ for $x$

Comment: Let me spell it out where we just look at the substitution in a vacuum, instead of probing a term with it (since I think this is causing confusion). Doing $(x\leftarrow y)$ followed by $(y\leftarrow z)$ will first take all the $x$'s and make them $y$'s and then all the $y$'s (including those that just became $y$ by the first substitution) and make them $z$'s. The combined action is $(x\leftarrow z, y\leftarrow z).$ $(y\leftarrow z)$ followed by $(x\leftarrow y)$ takes the $y$'s and makes them $z$'s and then takes the $x$'s and makes them $y$'s so is $(x\leftarrow y, y\leftarrow z).$

Comment: @Michelle I meant substitute $y$ *in* for $x,$ i.e. "plug in $y$ for $x$".

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen got it finally, thank you so much for your patience and guidance:)